# Using a potentiometer to control number of lit pixels on an NeoPixel strip

Tags: arduino-uno, potentiometer, neopixel

I'm working on controlling an [Adafruit NeoPixel strip](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/neopixel-strips) with an Arduino and a potentiometer. Specifically, I'm trying to use the potentiometer to control how many pixels are lit up on the strip. As I turn the potentiometer "up" (i.e., increasing the value), the number of lit-up pixels increases.

However, if I try to turn the potentiometer the other way and decrease the number of lit-up pixels, then the strip will stay at whatever the last value was.

I have a method below that's called during the 'void loop()' method that read in the potentiometer data:

```
void readAndSendPotentiometerDataIfChanged(void) {
 //Read data from analog pin 2, and scale it
 int newPotentiometerValue = analogRead(A2) / 5.68;   
  if (newPotentiometerValue != lastPotentiometerValue) {
      Serial.print("POT. value");
      Serial.print(newPotentiometerValue);
      lastPotentiometerValue = newPotentiometerValue;

      /* The value of "colorVal" is determined by a switch, and seems to be
         working properly */
      if (colorVal == "RED") {
        //If the value is 0, we want to clear the pixel values to white
        if (lastPotentiometerValue == 0) {
          clearPixels();
        } else {
          colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 0, 0)); // Red
        }
      } else if (colorVal == "BLUE") {
        if (lastPotentiometerValue == 0) {
          clearPixels();
        } else {
          colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 255)); // Blue
        }
      }
   }
}
```

The method below will clear out all 180 pixels on my strip to no color (clear).

```
void clearPixels() {
   uint16_t clearColor = (127, 127, 127);
   strip.setPixelColor(180, clearColor);
   strip.show();
}
```

Here's where the pixels on the strip get set...I'm sure the problem is in the for loop below, but I haven't been able to come up with a better way to set the pixels on the strip and then turn them on:

```
void colorWipe(uint32_t c) {

  /* Use the value of 'lastPotentiometerValue' to determine how many pixels 
   on the strip should be lit up */
  for(uint16_t i=0; i<lastPotentiometerValue; i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, c);
    delay(0.5);
  }
   strip.show();
}
```

Anyone have a pointer to how I could refactor my code so that the potentiometer works in both directions, and will light up or turn off the pixels on the strip as appropriate? Thank you!

**EDIT** Based on Ignacio's answer, I changed my `colorWipe` method to this:

```
void colorWipe(uint32_t c) {

  for (uint16_t i = lastPotentiometerValue; lastPotentiometerValue<180; i++){
      uint16_t clearColor = (127, 127, 127);
      strip.setPixelColor(i, clearColor);
  }

  for(uint16_t i=0; i<lastPotentiometerValue; i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, c);
    delay(0.5);
  }

   strip.show();
}
```

However, now no strips are lit up.

**EDIT 2**

The condition was wrong; below is the code that works:

```
void colorWipe(uint32_t c) {

  for(uint16_t i = lastPotentiometerValue; i<180; i++){
      uint16_t clearColor = (0, 0, 0);
      strip.setPixelColor(i, clearColor);
  }

  for(uint16_t i=0; i<lastPotentiometerValue; i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, c);
    delay(0.5);
  }

   strip.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to clear every *other* pixel in `colorWipe()`. Pixels that aren't sent a color retain their previous color.

Comment: That makes sense. So, something like (180-lastPotentiometerValue) would determine the pixels I need to clear, right?

Comment: No, everything from `lastPotentiometerValue` through 180.

Comment: That also makes sense; though I'm not sure how to keep that from resetting all the pixels (I made an edit to the question).

Comment: You goofed the condition.

Comment: How so? Apologies; not seeing what you're seeing :/

Comment: You need to compare `i`.